# Is the M1 Macbook Pro Magsafe charging indicator supposed to be always orange (charging on hold)?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe

Our developer team got new M1 Macbook Pros, and we've noticed that none of our magsafe charge indicators ever turn green (like the old magsafe). They all stay orange while plugged in with the laptop on. Most of these laptops are never unplugged. Even more odd is the battery pref pane shows plugged in charging the whole time with variations in battery level -- perhaps this is the new optimized charging?

Older macs showed "Fully Charged" even when "Optimized Battery Charging" was enabled. But these newer macs always show "Charging on Hold" in the battery pref pane (see below). Not a major issue, just curious if this is expected or not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there I bought mac pro m1  (my first apple device) but it does become green once fully charged

Comment: @Bhumit070 great -- are any of your battery options different than mine?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/9yEikYG7tSRm

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of enabling the optimized battery charging. Because you never unplug it, the computer is staying at a lower battery percentage.

You could test it, by clicking the battery icon and telling it to charge to full, however note that under the battery icon it says "Rarely used on battery." This is what's triggering it, and why some people may comment saying theirs becomes green. Unless theirs also shows that it's not at 100% and "Charging on hold" it's not the same condition.

While I can't definitively say that the orange is intended, I'm certain it's working properly otherwise based on your screenshots.

Comment: Nope. This is wrong. I have mine always plugged in and it usually is green. It's not always because of Apple's braindead idea of the battery can last longer by making it on battery more. But it turns green and it doesn't at the same time say rarely used on battery. It only says that when it's decided to not charge. When it hits 100% it's green. It shouldn't always be orange - which the question suggested it was. Now if it goes below 100 (or is about to hit 99%) then it should be orange. But if 100% it should be green.

Comment: I should also say that this happens whether optimised battery charging is enabled or not. I can enable it or disable it and then the next time I look at it's changed. So this isn't even just optimised battery charging. For example I thought it was enabled but I just checked and it's not. I don't recall doing this. I have also gone right back after changing it and it went back to what it was prior to supposedly changing it. It's very annoying.

Comment: There's two types of optimization. One will let the battery stay as low as 80% (as far as I know). The other one is much more subtle and cannot be turned off. This one changes what 100% means.