# M1 MacBook Pro charging indicator stays orange even while 100% charged

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power, magsafe

My MagSafe charger shows an orange light on my 16-inch M1 MacBook Pro (Late 2021) from time to time for hours/days when the lid is closed (monitor, webcam, microphone connected externally via USB-C). I.e., the charging process supposedly never ends, although it has long been completed according to the macOS display. Reconnecting the MagSafe then immediately causes it to turn green again. The problem does not occur every day but can be observed regularly.

In a nutshell:

1. Mac in standby, monitor off, MagSage orange
2. Disconnect and reconnect from MagSafe
3. Mac on, monitor on, MagSage immediately green

What is the problem? The MacBook was also affected by the (software/firmware) bug until the end of 2021, when the Macbook sometimes did not charge at all.
Thanks for any hint! :-)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's certainly been observed before: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439797/is-the-m1-macbook-pro-magsafe-charging-indicator-supposed-to-be-always-orange-c?rq=1

Comment: This is not "Charging on hold" ;-)